# CMI Error within cmi.log "Status : "10005", Error : "The requested resource was not found

Tags: clearcase

I am using `Base ClearCase` with **ClearQuest** using CMI according to the IBM document :
How to configure base ClearCase to use the Change Management integration with ClearQuest
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21633122

While checking out a file, I am getting the following error within cmi.log file:

> May 21,2015 12:23:22.574::ERROR::zxw378::Some Change Management providers failed to initialize! "Status : "10005", Error : "The requested resource was not found.
>   Session initialize failed for server at "http://usbri-app06/cqweb".
>   ", Warning : "", Information : ""."

ClearQuest Login with either Client or Browser works perfectly fine.
`cmiregister list -cq` command response looks correct.
`cleartool lsprovider -long -vob .` response looks correct.

Any idea what else to look for, because CHECKOUT fails to attach the TASK with the VERSION of the ELEMENT.

Comment: cleartool lstask -cview    response looks correct